# jquery if url contains?

Tags: jquery

I am using the following to create a scroll animation from a link at the top of a blog post to comments at the bottom on my site:

```
if (location.hash=='#comments') scrollToComments();
```

This works fine to scroll to #comments (i.e. the first comment). However, I would also like it to be able to scroll to an individual comment with the following id structure "#comment-%" e.g. "#comment-22".

Is there a way to do this in jquery?

Answer (score 1):

You could extract the hash, and scroll to the relevant element:

```
var hash = document.location.hash;
$(window).scrollTop($(hash).length ? $(hash).offset().top : 0);
```

Using a ternary to avoid problems with reading the `offset()` of a non-existent element/jQuery-object.

Answer (score 0):

If(regex.test(location.hash)){...}

For example (assuming the scrollTo plugin):

```
if(/^#comments/.test(location.hash)){
  $(window).scrollTo(location.hash, 'slow')
}
```

Comment: Wouldn't you be better off with indexOf in that case?

Comment: @prc322 hypothetically, if the hash is very long, the regex will be faster :-) and a suffix-match is not exactly easy with indexOf. You could still use `slice`.

Comment: neither `indexOf` nor `splice` can emulate this regex: `/^\#comments\-\d+$/`